# Apply a function to multiple rows of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to apply a function to different readings of each measure. Is it possible to do it without transforming the dataframe?

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': sorted(['A', 'B']*3),
    'measure': [i for i in range(0,3)]*2,
    'reading': [random.random() for i in range(0,6)]
})


  index  measure   reading
0     A        0  0.260492
1     A        1  0.805028
2     A        2  0.548699
3     B        0  0.014042
4     B        1  0.719705
5     B        2  0.398824
```

How can I apply a function like basic difference to different readings for each index?

Here I assumed function applied to reading 0 and 1. It should be part of the call as I need to calculate it for different values of measure.

Desired output looks like this:

```
  index  applied
0     A  0.5445359999999999
1     B  0.705663
```

Comment: `df.groupby('index')['reading'].diff()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks, I have more than 2 values for measures in my usecase and need to pass values for what to be included in the function going to be applied.

Comment: You should try reflecting that info with your sample data.

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry about that, updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': sorted(['A', 'B']*3),
    'measure': [i for i in range(0,3)]*2,
    'reading': [random.random() for i in range(0,6)]
})

print(df)

# index  measure   reading
# 0     A        0  0.869707
# 1     A        1  0.120680
# 2     A        2  0.772035
# 3     B        0  0.565548
# 4     B        1  0.577074
# 5     B        2  0.290668

start = 0
stop = 1

# I decided to specify start and stop value separately, the absolute difference is 
# calculated via np.sum(). If the difference between start and stop is always 1, you 
# can omit the np.sum() call.

df = df.groupby('index').agg(applied=('reading', lambda x: np.sum(np.diff(x) 
[start:stop])))

print(df)

#         applied
# index
# A     -0.749027
# B      0.011526
```

Comment: Thanks @Franz Forstmayr, It's a credible answer, but I need a little more freedom in choosing the measure (for example when it's a string value or not in a series like 0,1,..).

Comment: gimme some example please